# creating and running jar file with source

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7

I write a very simple java program with two classes: `Business` and `Main`.

I want to create a jar such that if I email it to someone they can:

- run the program (i.e. run the jar)
- open the jar to view the source code.
- the code can run on mac or windows

I have been using IDEs for so long I have forgotten how to do this.

I am using netbeans 7.x

EDIT:

I found the following way on Netbeans:

```
properties > packaging > exclude from jar file :: delete **/*.java
```

But when I try to execute the jar using

```
java -jar mybusiness.jar
```

it says

```
no main manifest attribute, in mybusiness.jar
```

But note that my jar has a main class. Am I missing a manifest file?

Comment: someone says to make sure project.properties contains `manifest.file=manifest.mf` but I can't see where to set that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a JAR file that includes the source code using Netbeans:

1. Right click on the project and select properties
2. Build -> Packaging
3. Remove Java files from the excluded files. And select build jar after compiling

It will create the jar file that includes the source code if it successfully compiles.

Comment: When I try to run it with `java -jar mybusiness.jar` it says `no main manifest attribute, in mybusiness.jar`

Comment: Most probably you need to add the main class in your manifest file. Add a line similar to this one:
Main-Class: com.mypackage.Main
Just change the package name to yours

Answer (score 0):

Well surely an IDE can do this too?. Just make some text files and put the source into them and drag them into the ide's. It's java so it should automatically run on all platforms. I am not sure what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) explains how do u create manifest file and how do you specify your main class in manifest file as its necessary for executing jar.